# How to react to unfair downvotes that seem to be from the same user

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

I think most of us have had the feeling at least once, that you think someone has unfairly downvoted your answer (which otherwise is a perfectly correct answer, undoubtedly).

I had some answers like that downvoted just recently, so I used the [where-we-met tool](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/25355/have-we-met) to check upon the person who I think might have downvoted me.

It might be a coincidence, but the downvoted answers are exactly those where we have met.

How do I react to this? It'd be quite childish to go ahead and pay him/her back with downvotes. Should I at least try to contact this person offline to ask why the anger?

This has happened a few more times afterwards; same scenario.

Whenever I cross paths with this user on a question, my rival answer gets down-voted. Surely, it doesn't have to be him/her. However, if I respond by down-voting the user's answer (next to mine), suddenly one of my old, totally unrelated and accepted answers gets randomly down-voted.

This is the only occasion when I get down-voted on my old rusty answers. I tried contacting the user offline to no avail. A bit disappointing, yet funny enough.

Comment: What you do on your own time outside of the site is your own business.  Personally, I'd just shrug it off.

Comment: "How do I react to this? It'd be quite childish to go ahead and pay him/her back with downvotes." Consider that if they really did downvote your post unfairly, then it was childish of *them* to have done so. Congratulations, you've already become the better person without having to *do anything*.

Comment: Of course, you don't know for sure if the downvote was for a bogus reason or a legitimate one. But if *you* react in a way that you *know* is childish, then you're the one who's lost.

Comment: On [your "rep" tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1768303/noseratio?tab=reputation&sort=post), I see a grand total of two downvotes on you in the last week.  Is there something else going on, or votes that got reversed, likely by the anti-troll script?

Comment: Note that if this is happening regularly then one of two things probably applies: (1) you have a sworn--perhaps even arch--enemy who is out to get you and whose votes will likely be reversed sooner or later by the serial vote script or (2) maybe you don't know as much as you think.

Comment: What makes you think it's anger? Maybe I just [misplaced my keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-down-voting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) (a big contributor to this phenomenon).

Comment: @dmckee, I've had perfectly relevant down-votes before from the people who knows more than I do, and I accepted those gratefully. BTW, they usually were given with very helpful comments. In this particular case however, I'm confident the answers are correct.

Comment: Fair enough. My comments really only apply if you are getting these votes on a non-trivial fraction of your posts.

Comment: @TimPost, the phenomenon-of-the-misplaced-keys idea already makes me feel better about this, thanks! :)

Comment: That sounds like a very dangerous tool, I often visit the same tags that you post to.  Just in case: it wasn't me.  Downvotes on good answers happen, two of them in a matter of weeks is nothing unusual.

Comment: @Noseratio I think you're taking it all too seriously at this point: just walk away and realize that these are random people on the Internet who are free to vote as they please and will certainly exercise that freedom. Don't worry about it and move on: you can't know for certain whether a single person is downvoting your answers intentionally, and it's not a big deal in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: You've got 23100 points.  What are they good for?  Why would you care whether you get a few more or a few less?

Comment: (I handle this situation the same way I handle idiot drivers: laugh.  They're the ones raising their blood pressure and driving themselves to an early grave.)

Comment: Just dont downvote unless the answer actually deserves it. How is it fair to the OP if the best answer is downvoted just because you have a childish argument with someone else?

Comment: I think SO should implement some sort of engine that looks for repeated downvotes by one member that targets another specific member. Surely there could be some sort of algorithm to detect this disconcerting situation--especially if other users aren't downvoting the same question/answer. However it is defined, one user should be limited as to how many times they can downvote another user in a given time period, otherwise--thanks to the anonymity of downvoting--vendettas (as rare as they hopefully are) can spawn and thrive on SO's networks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Revisiting this has got me thinking. Apparently, SO has become much more than a hobby, *if I was bothered that much*. This is not normal.

The time I've been increasingly spending on SO over the last year has already started eating into my other hobbies. I dare to admit it, it probably has even started to affect my productivity at work. Now, *this is seriously wrong.*

Thanks everyone for helping me get to understand this. Including the guy I was going to chase.

Comment: I couldn't agree more

Comment: And thats how good people started to diminish away from SO communities. They "moved on" from the bad guys. Great Job SO

Answer (score 49):

> Should I at least try to contact this person offline to check why the
>   anger?

How about bake them a cake or bring them some beer? Nah. Save that for your own consumption!

In the great scheme of things, **who cares**. That is my philosophy towards ultimately non-threatening online interactions. And this is coming from someone who has—indeed—taken troll bait online and have grown to realize all that was gained from the effort was wasting my time and sanity for 100% of nothing.

Yes, your gut reaction initially might be to “resolve the issue” since none of want to live life in conflict, but the reality is you are just better off moving forward and ignoring the distractions.

And FWIW, remember when gym teachers would tell you to calm down by taking 5-10 minutes to walk around the track? At least I do and you know what? It works! When something gets me nutty at my day job I literally leave the building, take a quick walk around the block and then go back to work. It takes the edge off because at the end of the day you will not say, “Oh, why! Oh, why! Why did someone on the Internet downvote me! Will future generations solve this question once and for all!”

Also, some other advice: If you are dealing with a real sociopath who just pushes buttons to manipulate and cause a reaction, they will not care if you ask them what the deal is. They are simply cold to you and using you to make them feel better. So if you actually did reach out to them in real life, all you are ultimately doing is rewarding a sociopath for their antisocial behavior.

You ever see how cops and security guards ignore people? It’s not a healthy way to deal with regular social interactions, but the case of B.S. like this, cool heads prevail. You really need to detach yourself from clowns.

Comment: @JakeCould, a great advice, thanks. Ironically, I like the guy, and I myself up-voted a lot of his question/answers before. To keep it further this way, I thought I'd at least ask him.

Comment: @JakeCould, you're in danger, apparently there's an angry school student coming after you there! You should report this serial down-voting to the mods (use the report link next to the question). I was in a [similar situation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216953/suspicious-accounts-copying-my-bounty-answer) once, and the problem was resolved that way, the voted were reversed. If it doesn't work out for you this way, I'll personally up-vote each of those posts.

Comment: @Jake I would agree you, if downvotes without a reason would not lead to bans or similar things.

Comment: @NeilG there's plenty of people who claim to care about thigh repusers abusing downvoting, but few (none?) have shown evidence of that outside of one off honest mistakes. :shrug:

Answer (score 23):

The humor of the [theory of lost keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-down-voting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) aside, if negative votes aren't *clearly* signal, then they're noise. Ignore the noise.

You're assuming something sort of ominous, that *somewhere*, there's *someone* that knows more about your answer than you do and isn't telling you what's wrong with it. It's generally the complete opposite of that, someone probably just didn't understand it, or some Sanka-drinking neckbeard wearing a corduroy sport coat picked the question you answered to pretend to play Zelda.

If *you* can't find anything wrong with it, and no one else is telling you what *could* be wrong with it, filter out the noise and find something more fun to think about.

I tend to pay more attention to random down votes on *old* posts, because they can sometimes indicate that one of my answers is no longer as relevant as it once was, and folks are trying to get a better answer to the surface. But that's the sort of thing you can figure out quickly, if you can't - don't obsess over it.

Answer (score 6):

I honestly can't believe this is real, but I was asked to respond, so I will.

**Short Story**:
Noseratio strongly misunderstands the OP's question, posts an answer that adds no value to the discussion, gets rightfully downvoted and reponds by going through my old answers (in unrelated tags) and downvoting them. The cherry on top is coming here blaming the victim.

**Long Story**:

- I answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966167/885318) with what is now the top [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966167/885318) by more than X2 (including his downvote).
- Noseratio arrives, misunderstands the question and [asks for clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966019/async-with-huge-data-streams/24966167#comment38807362_24966167), which I gave and [at least 3 people approved of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966019/async-with-huge-data-streams/24966167#comment38807444_24966167).
- Disregarding it he posts an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966573/885318) irrelevant to the both the question **and** to the other 3 answers.
- While being [confronted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966019/async-with-huge-data-streams/24966167#comment38853562_24966573) by other members, he comments on the question for [clarification from the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966019/async-with-huge-data-streams/24966167#comment38852780_24966019) which days later still hasn't arrived.
- Naturally he's being downvoted so he takes it out on my answer, which clearly ins't incorrect and goes after [my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24954136/885318) in fields he [doesn't even participate in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958293/885318). (which he's openly touting about in this post)
- After all that, he puts a bounty on this question (which I can only guess is meant to encourage the OP to mark his answer and give him back his reputation)
- Lastly, he comes here to complain about **my** behavior?

Noseratio should delete his answer, retract his spiteful downvotes and get on with his life.

Comment: As long as you've brought this up... 1) It's impossible for me to reward a bounty to myself, but I do hope to see an answer from an expert. 2) **As to down-votes.** When my answer was downvoted, I down-voted yours ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24966167/1768303)). I then received a bunch of downvotes to [my old questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1768303/noseratio?tab=reputation). The **only** other downvote I gave back is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953808/write-your-own-async-method/24954136#24954136).

Comment: @Noseratio Well, maybe I got 4 totally unrelated downvotes in an hour, which is more than I got the entire year since I started participating. Unlikely, but possible...

Comment: In this light, I suggest you report this to SO and to the mods. I just did that and I'm going to undo the two negative votes I gave you.

Comment: @l3arnon, previously the same thing happened to me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23959348/1768303) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23966050/1768303), where we both crossed. Could there be someone trying to orchestrate a tension between you and me? I don't know, but I hope the mods could find out.

Comment: @Noseratio no, we just evidently fundamentally disagree on what is a useful answer for an OP (even [when he's me](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21468137/885318)). But I'll tell you what... I'll go over your tool and retract every single vote I gave you and vow to never give one in the future.

Comment: @l3arnon, you don't need to revoke you votes, it's perfectly fine to disagree and argue within the context of the same question. What was making me sad is that someone was downvoting my old and totally unrelated posts. As long as it wasn't you, I have my peace of mind back.

Comment: @Noseratio It was me, responding to what I saw as a targeted attack (though I'm still puzzled by the remaining 2 unrelated downvotes in  an hour). Anyway, I retracted everything, and you should probably (if you want) edit these questions back to remove my gravatar.

Comment: @l3arnon, report those two. If they are not reverted, let me know, I'll personally upvote them.

Comment: @Noseratio No need, that's fine. Thanks...