# Is there any automation to detect/stop shill behaviour?

Tags: discussion, voting

I haven't been very active on Stack Overflow lately, because I've been travelling, but now after one night back there I've already been bugged by an issue which really grated my nerves the last time I was quite active.

It's the issue of friends [shilling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shill#Verb) for each other, upvoting/accepting only answers from their group. This is primarily an issue which is really obvious with the Indian community, but obviously it will exist on some scale within every group.

Time and time again I will take the time to answer an Indian user's post, sometimes even looking up a code sample just to help the poster. One of their friends will then repost the same thing or a slight rewording of it hours later and that answer will be upvoted and accepted, sometimes the original answer is even downvoted.

Now as there's no way to actually report that behaviour, because we want to encourage multiple solutions. Is there at least a mechanism in place that detects a pattern of behaviour like this and limits it? Would this be a valid feature request otherwise?

Comment: How do you know they are friends?

Comment: @juanchopanza because they're *Indian* - that's a pretty small population of people..

Comment: If someone copies your answer exactly or doesn't change enough it enough to make it entirely their own words, and doesn't properly attribute you and your answer as the source, then you can flag the post for plagiarism: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299777/what-should-be-done-with-users-found-guilty-of-plagiarism

Comment: there is a script that detects this and reverts all those votes [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/230282), although I think it's almost impossible to make it work correctly in all cases [Do serial voting detection scripts really work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223519/230282)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253454/995714 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261545/995714

Comment: @Raystafarian Being Indian puts you in one of the largest populations of human beings in the world. Maybe what the OP really wants is a script that predicts and interprets behavior based solely on one's race.

Comment: @Superstringcheese your rudeness is especially Ironic given that a look at your meta history highlights a negatively scored answer in which you express the opinion that posting the same answer (even with more doc) is wrong, which is a prerequisite of this issue. juanchopanza I said friends because I assumed it would be more likely that the users would know each other in these cases than to be voting that way just because of nationality,

Comment: @NickCardoso Pointing to any community is itself rudeness that you have shown. Being an indian I agree with you, by asking [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262345/is-it-ok-to-ask-your-friends-to-upvote-your-posts) I also wanted to ask for same to SO. pointing to any nationality or community is really offensive I feel. specially for those who are belonging to that community or nationality and following all SO rules (like me) :(. I feel, you can ask this question in other words...

Comment: @NickCardoso as a honest Indian  user who loves  stack overflow and contributes to it ,  I do not see how naming and generalizing  the Indian community  has any relevance to the problem at hand. 

I find it offensive, I hope you know that there are 29 states in India and many of them are bigger than countries in Europe.

Comment: @Superstringcheese [whoosh!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whoosh) Yes, that was the joke that Raystafarian was making. I'm pretty sure most people know that India is the second-most populated country in the world by a wide margin.

Comment: poor indians :D :D

Comment: Woah, subtle racism at its finest!

Comment: How do you know they are Indians or Whatever Nationality?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Yes, there are tools for this, and this is something moderators put a lot of effort into investigating. We can pick up when particular users are coordinating questions, answers, and votes between coworkers, friends, or falsified accounts. I obviously won't detail those tools, but they work very well.

The system will invalidate strings of serial votes between accounts, but it doesn't catch everything and is designed to be conservative about vote invalidation. It also doesn't remove accounts, provide suspensions, or take more serious action beyond the vote invalidation. A human always has to make the judgment call on whether more action is needed or to deal with cases where someone has worked around the system.

We find many of these cases ourselves, due to early warning systems we have or just the intuition we've built up after seeing people pull the same schemes year over year. Everyone thinks they are the first ones to try this, but the patterns are easy to see. Others are brought to our attention by the community.

If you see what looks like clear coordination between a few users, or a new user asking poor questions yet getting crazy upvotes on each one, you can flag one of their posts with a custom flag and describe what made you suspicious. A single post getting a couple of extra votes probably isn't enough for us to act on. If you see one person only ever answering questions by another person (and immediately getting those answers accepted) or someone writing terrible posts that always seem to get 2+ upvotes, that might be worth checking into.

Unfortunately, most of this behavior does tend to come from a particular area of the world. We even have evidence that how to defraud the Stack Overflow voting system is being taught to new employees at specific companies. In the end, it doesn't help them, as we will wipe the votes, delete meat puppet or sock puppet accounts, and suspend the accounts involved. They will end up no better than they started, and in fact may get their entire company blocked from posting anything.

It's important to me that people be able to trust the voting system here, so this is something we do spend a lot of time on. Moderators have worked with Stack Exchange to make these tools more effective at catching problematic users before the community notices, but any site this size is going to have some people who slip through.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to detect serial *non*-voting. Such as never voting for a user and voting up all competing answers to push the user's answers to the bottom.

Comment: *We even have evidence that how to defraud the Stack Overflow voting system is being taught to new employees at specific companies.* I'm speechless. I will consider that behavior with new eyes now. Thank you for making that information public.

Comment: @Mysticial - To be honest, I don't know that I've ever seen that happen. Almost all people trying to manipulate the voting system are extremely lazy. These aren't criminal masterminds we're dealing with. We're talking about people who create sock puppet accounts that have the exact same name as their main account. My personal favorite was [username]'s sock puppet that was named "[username] vote up account".

Comment: Wooow, I watch forensics and I've heard of criminals using their victim's credit cards and signing their own name. This is a new level of stupidity. :)

Comment: What about instances where they might not be a tight consistent group but all answers are upvoted/downvoted/accepted based on the race of the poster? As a theoretical example, an Indian user only voting for fellow Indians. Practically impossible to prove intent but a frustrating pattern to other users nonetheless. Are there any options available to us?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a 'correct answer' to a discussion, but this did answer the whole question!

Comment: *"If you see what looks like clear coordination between a few users"*.  What about the "close vote review" chat room? It is a relic of a time when users were focused on the six figure close vote review queue. That is no longer an issue and often these users collude to close questions immediately based on the direction of only a few users. One user requests a close vote and often the same group of other users will all vote accordingly. Does this count towards your metric, or are you only addressing voting which leads to reputation?

Comment: @TravisJ - We can easily pull apart groups of people associated with a particular chatroom vs. those all operating out of the same physical location. Any active user in a popular tag is going to show targeted voting in their direction (I love using Eric Lippert as a great example when working to remove false positives from our tools). We'd only care about a chatroom coordinating votes if they were using them to maliciously target people or clearly forming a voting ring that wasn't based on the quality of the posts they were voting on. Chatrooms are almost never the source of any of this.

Comment: Did you take a look at the OP's answer history, by chance? Of course I am not seeing any deleted answers that may exist, but looking at the negative-scored answers, all I see is a history of being mildly insulting to the OP of questions and link-only answers -- answers that I would downvote if I encountered them during normal browsing. The subject of the OP may be valid, but I think it does bear mentioning that not all downvotes are part of some orchestrated plot, especially when you call people "lazy" or your tone implies they're idiots.

Comment: I guess my point is that the presumption of bad faith isn't where things should start off. If you got a downvote, introspection should be the first stop. The recent answers seem fine, but I can definitely see some posts that totally deserved the DVs it got.

Comment: @ChrisBaker - I don't think the thrust of this question had to do with downvotes they had received, but perceived voting coordination that boosted possibly low-quality posts past theirs. Those are two slightly different issues, and we examine them in different ways. For a pattern of downvotes going from one user to another, it can sometimes be difficult to determine if they were due to post quality or not. We do examine these to see if there is an indication that someone isn't reading the posts in question (votes coming seconds apart, etc.) and SE employees check this also before invalidation.

Comment: But _why_ do people do this? Why is gaining a reasonable amount of reputation on Stack Overflow a goal? Is it that there are companies who hire people based on their SO profile? And do they stop looking after seeing the reputation? I've seen plenty of high-rep users who I wouldn't trust to write a simple CRUD web app, because they lack knowledge on so many subjects, yet excel in a very small subset (as in: giving the same answer over and over again on slightly different questions). Why do people care _that much_ about reputation?

Comment: @CodeCaster I scored a 5k€ Project based on my SO profile. The customer looked at "who is in my region, has 2k+ Rep on SO and a java badge." I still wonder how he got that "region" thing right, as many people don't state their region in the profile, but I guess that was all the better for me :) - So, yeah, SO rep matters and I live in Germany.

Comment: @Angelo time to put my profile on my resume then...

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, I can totally recommend that!

Comment: @CodeCaster I get a lot of work through StackOverflow so reputation is important. If you open and read random profiles there's a lot of people specifically touting for work so I think it's pretty common to get approached because of your profile here

Comment: @CodeCaster - Of the people I've seen do this over the last year, a significant majority are doing it to evade question bans. A common pattern is to get question-banned on an account, then create a second account and use the first to vote for it so it never can be banned. Again, we have evidence that companies are teaching employees how to avoid question bans with tactics like this. Stopping a ring of users like this might prevent 100 bad questions from ever hitting the site, which is why I believe better measures to prevent question-ban evasion could have a huge impact on overall quality.

Comment: @Brad yeah if you actually can't program but only copy-paste, you'll have to take drastic measures like that to allow you to keep posting "debug this for me" rubbish... It's really sad that companies recognize this, hire poor programmers and encourage them to outsource their debugging to SO.

Comment: @BradLarson: "*forming a voting ring that wasn't based on the quality of the posts*" - so a voting ring that is based on quality of posts is legit? I should totally start one.

Comment: @Bergi I think a "voting ring" by definition is a group whose goals are contrary to those of the site. If you're just trying to encourage good content, "voting ring" isn't really an appropriate term.

Comment: Say you have a group of 50 people, they all agree to up vote one post of a “member” each day, and also up vote 3 or 4 other posts each day.  They also decide to never up vote a post of a member unless the post has already been up voted by someone else.     This will be close to impossible for any script to detach!    @BradLarson, You may be mostly seeing simple extremely lazy vote manipulate, as these are the easy cases to catch.

Comment: @IanRingrose - As I've stated above, almost all people doing this are extremely lazy and do the most obvious things possible. More elaborate voting schemes are few and far between. No automated system is perfect, which is where a little detective work and / or help from the community comes in. If moderators or users see low quality or wrong content getting anomalously high votes, that can clue us in that something is wrong. We don't entirely rely on the system to determine that something's off about voting in an area. Human intuition is still a strong part of the process.

Answer (score 15):

If you are sure it is abusive (you can **verify** that the same user is only accepting answers from one other person, and the answers posted are very similar to the ones others posted), you could flag one of the questions with a custom flag reason.

Tell there you suspect the users to be part of a vote ring, why you expect that, which evidence you found, etc. Then let the moderators handle it.

Comment: Well as much as i dont like it, im not sure it can ever count as abusive

Comment: Well, this is the only "pattern of behavior" you can see as being abusive. A related question from me on MSE on "region based voting", in this case during moderator elections: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252934/245360.