# Encouraging SO at work and Sock Puppet/Fraud detection

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting, voting-fraud

I recently have been encouraging my colleagues to post more to SO.  Instead of emailing the team, have them write up a SO question and email around the SO question link instead so that we can involve and contribute to the community.

This will inevitably result in us up-voting each other's questions (if they are well written) and (hopefully) answering each other's questions.

In [Is there any automation to detect/stop shill behaviour?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300810/is-there-any-automation-to-detect-stop-shill-behaviour) moderator Brad Larson indicated:

> We [Moderators] can pick up when particular users are coordinating questions, answers, and votes between coworkers

**Question:**  a) If my colleagues and I vote for each other's questions, will we get banned and b) does this violate the spirit of SO?

**Bonus Question:** Does stackexchange (plan to) offer a private 'SO' for internal use at companies?  Or is that what [Confluence Q&A](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence-questions) is for.

Comment: If your votes target people rather than posts then yes you do stand the risk of being banned. There is a private 'SO' for large corporates, I understand it's expensive. There are various lookalikes you could find by searching.

Comment: Using SO instead of internal mails seems rather ... backwards? Why not rely on internal knowledge first and only post if you can't figure it out? And yeah, just don't vote for each other's stuff. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: And to save your from having to search, here is a list of clones: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones

Comment: @Bart - Posting to SO forces them to "google" the question first.  Perhaps someone in the community could answer it better (in which case everyone in the company benefits).  If the question is not on SO and we answer it, then SO benefits.  And thanks for the link to the clones question!

Comment: Even though your colleagues might be better prepared to judge each others' posts (since they have a similar background knowledge), I'd advise to not vote for each others' posts.  It's really a conflict of interest, even if the votes are legitimate.  It's like a company creating a sweepstakes and putting in the "employees and immediate family are ineligible" clause.

Comment: @PhilipPittle Posting on [so] unfortunately does not **force** any searching on Google. We encourage people to search and share their results - [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - but we still get far too many questions posted where users have not done any research at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> a) If my colleagues and I vote for each other's questions, will we get
>   banned

I would think that if the accounts involved were only used for this sort of in-office communication you would probably get some unwanted attention from the mods and the community.

On the other hand if the accounts were well rounded, real accounts; as in you aren't afraid to downvote your co-workers when they deserve it and the the accounts participate in other normal community activities, you probably won't have much to worry about.

> b) does this violate the spirit of SO?

As mentioned before, if the accounts involved are well rounded, I don't think it would violate the spirit of SO.

If you're adding quality content to the knowledge base that can help people outside of your office you're doing the community a service. If you can kill two birds with one stone I don't see any harm in it.

Answer (score 5):

> Will we get banned?

Possibly, if you actually trigger the voting scripts.

> Does this violate the spirit of SO?

IMO, yes.  Even though your colleagues might be better prepared to judge each others' posts (since they have a similar background knowledge), I'd advise to not vote for each others' posts. It's really a conflict of interest, even if the votes are legitimate. It's like a company creating a sweepstakes and putting in the "employees and immediate family are ineligible" clause.