# How easy is it to "farm" reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting-fraud, sock-puppets

What does Stack Overflow do to prevent people farming reputation, such as creating multiple accounts, having them all ask questions, having them all selecting them as best answer, up voting his answers, repeat?

Comment: It's very very easy! You might get some inspiration by looking at this [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979914/1842065). And please do notice my comment below the accepted answer as it's very relevant. He never gave up, even when caught, and is currently sitting at +3985. If you'd sum up all the accounts you'd probably end up with a 5 digit number. That's pretty impressive for a novice who barely knows how to program. Good luck!

Comment: It's not worth the effort, either to do it or to prevent it. If you want lots of rep quickly, study the questions that get huge numbers of upvotes and emulate them.

Comment: using any cheating methods to farm some vitrual points, cheaters are losing their reputation in the eyes of other users

Comment: the path to earn reputation is simple but unlikely easy: 1. became a professional or an expert in some tag/tags 2. post helpful answers 3. profit! related reading - `Stack Overflow reputation and being a micro celebrity` by  @JonSkeet (http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/01/15/stack-overflow-reputation-and-being-a-micro-celebrity/)

Comment: It happens, usually the only practical way for students to gain rep in a hurry.   Hard to detect unless they keep it going, which is rare.  Voting rings do get detected and larsoned if the participants don't stop, that's a heckofalot of effort with nothing to show for it :)  Of course nobody will tell you exactly *how* they are detected, ought to be obvious.  Why do you ask?

Comment: Related: ["Is there any automation to detect/stop shill behaviour?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300810/is-there-any-automation-to-detect-stop-shill-behaviour)

Comment: You don't need multiple accounts. Just ask high-quality questions and post high-quality answers (even on the same thread), and other people will do the voting for you :-)

Comment: You should see the angular2 questions. People keep asking the same questions over and over, and the high rep users keep answering them when SO has mechanisms to mark questions as duplicates, but they don't care, they keep answering them, easy rep. That's why I'm giving up on answering on SO, this is not about helping anyone anymore but hunting rep points.

Comment: I noticed that the answer I linked to in my previous comment were removed (along with all the valuable information), so here's an image for non 10k'ers: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YTpYl.png

Comment: “Farming” rep is pretty easy without technically abusing the system. I decided to “grind” my way to 10k from about 5k, and I did it in a couple months, and I really wasn’t even spending that much time answering questions. It could be done much faster. I just answered lots of crappy questions in popular tags. I’m not proud of it, but it worked. Now that I’ve hit 10k, I only answer good questions in tags I’m interested in, and my reputation gain has slowed *considerably* because of it. I think there is little doubt that the system encourages *some* kinds of poor behavior.

Answer (score 49):

> prevent

There aren't any mechanical safeguards in place preventing anyone from creating multiple OpenID (or some other SSO) credentials and creating accounts with them.

We just have scripts that invalidate blatant incidents of serial voting after the fact (leaving a nasty mark on someone's reputation history), and flags and moderators to police this sort of activity, deleting sock puppets and suspending offenders.

Only a person's own integrity can keep them in check.

Comment: Note that this is something quite different from a group of users voting exclusively for one another - the group as a whole may not realize that they're biasing their votes too much on one another and we handle such cases differently, but a single user creating socks or soliciting votes from people they know is knowingly cheating the system.

Comment: One good possibility: http://stackapps.com/questions/6729/stack-overflow-vote-fraud-script

Comment: @CiroSantilli, Doesn't exist anymore, seems like the mods are pretty seriously effective :-)

Comment: @JonasCz: Speaking of which, I *might* have burned the OP to smithereens with my answer. Oops.

Comment: @JonasCz by coincidence it just got autoremoved it seems. Shame, since the more downvotes that got, the better. Here's gitHub: https://github.com/cirosantilli/stack-overflow-vote-fraud-script

Comment: I'm not sure that the mark is so *nasty* RE:`Should I be concerned about these correction statements on my profile?`
`No, not at all. It's only an indication of reputation change. After all, we can't control the actions of other users. `   http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 It looks weird to me to "advertise" that repo in a comment on SO. Can you explain your choice to do that? \[Disclaimer: I _have seen_ [this](https://github.com/cirosantilli/stack-overflow-vote-fraud-script/blob/master/motivation.md). Are you trying to force an issue here?]

Comment: @sehe I just though it was fun / pertinent to this thread. I don't see any way to get money from that repo + will likely generate more bad than good rep ;-) Intentions are good though. If the community wants to audit the current blackbox rep reversal system, that script can help.

Comment: Who mentioned money? ([meaning 2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316702/how-easy-is-it-to-farm-reputation?cb=1#comment308428_316703)). I can't be sure of your claims, but it looks to me that it would give the wrong people the wrong clues. If SO were _my_ site, I'd ban resources like this. Oh wait...

Comment: @sehe I believe real hackers will always have the best closed source hacking tools. I'd put more trust in a transparent website with an open algorithm + known failed attacks. If openness actually possible, we can never convince each other ;-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 I'm completely with you. But then there is moderated site content (this is not the place) and responsible disclosure (debatable here, I don't know the ins and outs of the offsensive and defensive parts here)

Comment: @sehe I think it might be pertinent: "How easy is it to “farm” reputation?" Answer: we don't know, it's a black box. But this script can help you reverse engineer it / find out. If it is acceptable or not to post such links here, that would make for a nice meta question ;-) (but could draw more attention to that script >:-) )

Comment: So, if it answers the question, why not post that answer...

Comment: @Boris Treukhov: I mean, a small mark may be a result of someone else's over-enthusiastic voting in which case it's harmless, but have you ever seen someone with a -2000 mark on their profile? That is pretty damning if you ask me.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩: you do realise that anyone caught using your methods is going to have to face serious consequences, right? That includes you yourself. We take voting fraud very seriously, by whatever means.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do. That is why I recommend that you use it on someone else, not yourself, and only to audit the system (disclose later if not found). Of course, if someone decides to use it one someone else, I'm the obvious target... But I don't see how you can get the real attacker's ID from behind Tor.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩: and your motivations are.. simplistic at best, foolhardy and non-constructive in any other light. *Let's force them to move to a more robust algorithm*, as if that's a simple switch.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩: and using this on another user doesn't make this any less fraudulent. You are still wilfully trying to skew votes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters totally agree it is fraudulent. I just don't see how the puppet master could get caught. Don't worry though, it's likely too much hassle for anyone to actually do it. And too great a risk for anyone who has enough answers.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩: let me suffice to say that if I see any odd behaviour on the site you'll be the first to get my undivided attention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair enough. It is useless to say this, but I'm not carrying the attack now, lost a bit of interest. Maybe later :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩: sure, I totally believe you. What's honesty between friends, eh?

Comment: @MartijnPieters ;-)

Answer (score 20):

Stack Overflow has some automated scripts to detect and prevent abuses. Reputation should be given **only for those who deserve it** to keep other users motivated to contribute.

Usually, those who create sock puppets to farm reputation use this method because they have poor skills and can't earn reputation by their own merit. This makes them easier to detect because they leave a trace of bad content.

If someone creates sock puppets that post **quality content** and only upvote  the main account once or twice (*i.e.*, the abuse is very small), it's somewhat harder to detect. However, if it's **quality content**, we have this famous XKCD comic to think on:

[image: xkcd]

<sup>PS: I don't support sock puppets in any way. Just want to emphasize that **I believe** that sock puppets that posts quality content are harder to identify and causes less damage.</sup>

Comment: But what will you do when real users throw epic fits about their contributions being downvoted and rated as "not constructive"?

Comment: Say "We can't do anything about that years-old question because we abolished 'not constructive' years ago." It was replaced with "primarily opinion-based", which means roughly the same thing (that it meets the ["don't ask" criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)) but is easier for new users to understand.

Answer (score 4):

I used to put a similar question on SO some years ago with some "suggestions" of possible frauds. I lost over night 200 points on downvoting over night and finally the question was removed :-)

Actually, someone from SO even bothered to comment some of "my suggestions". They wrote, SO detects some upvoting patterns (e.g. if two persons upvote each other all the time)

I think, what SO is concerned is keeping SO serious, so the people continue input their knowledge in the system. If the frauds are not so obvious and the questions the "fraudster" puts are unique and interesting - SO wouldn't care.

But why to care about the reputation so much? The most of my colleges only use SO for look-up. They use SO many times without bothering to create an account. One even told, at their company having an account on SO is considered as a negative thing - because the people may spend the time answering the questions there not for work but for their ego.

Answer (score 0):

I just laughed a lot when I found this question. Stack Overflow is not like a game for going and farming your coin. Also it is just a place for developers or whoever can help each other by sharing their knowledge and experience on the matter stated in the question.

Just try answer when you know your answer does really work and help others. Reputation mean nothing; what is earning is a thanks and good feeling.

However, to earn reputation (to farm, haha), you have to participate more often.

- Reputation less than a thousand can help edit to improve other questions or answers. You will earn a few reputation.
- Be the first to answer a question. (Make sure your answer does help.)
- Participate in the comment section and improve your answer as better as you can.
- Ask good questions.
- Well-designed questions and answers will attract readers.
- Learn more and continue to ask or answer if it is helpful.
- You can ask and answer your own post. (But it does not mean to do it all the time. Unless you think it helps others, and others will help to share a better solution on your matter.)

Never answer if you don't know, else you will attract more downvotes.
Oh, whenever you downvote other answers, think clearly because it will reduce your own reputation too.

Comment: Downvoting questions does not cost reputation points.

Comment: Ah, yes. Only downvoting answer cost reputation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down. I edited my post. Thanks

Comment: `Join group chats.` - no? Only main site contributions count towards rep, chat doesn't help with that. Unless you count a concealed voting ring, but that isn't specifically good...